# How to change the path in command prompt using java

Tags: java, automation, command-prompt

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

import autoitx4java.AutoItX;

public class SilentInstallation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String[] cmd = { "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "start" };
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = runtime.exec(cmd);
        }

        catch (java.io.IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + exception.getMessage());

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my code in which I am running command prompt using java. But the problem here I am facing is I can't be able to change the path in command prompt using java code.

Since this code is using in Automation, so is there any command or method in java that can be used to change the path in the command prompt.

I have also used ProcessBuilder to change the directory path. 
Any Recommendations.....

Comment: Show the code where you used `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
Process p = ...
p.getOutputStream().write("cd d:\\/r/n".getBytes());
```